# How do I get values from a single row placed into an array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find out how to get data from a single row in a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

I've managed to get data from a single column in a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script but when I adjust the range for a single row with multiple columns it comes back different.

Basically I think it is coming to me as a comma-separated list but I need it to be in an array-like what I'm getting when I use the code below.

Here is the code I am using to get data from a single column

```
var temp = activeSheet.getRange("A1:A6").getValues();
```

Comment: They're always arrays. They're not a comma separated list. If the above linked questions don't answer your question satisfactorily, [edit] your question to show why it's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the values from a single row is to use

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('1:1').getValues()[0];
```

The above code will return all the values for the first row from the active sheet.

NOTES:

`getValues()` return an Array of Arrays, where each inner Array corresponds to each range row. The inner array elements are ordered according to the range columns.

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: Can you tell me what this means? like the part you added what does that do?

`
[0];
`

Comment: @AaronD I adited my answer.